Employment status categories that include pensioners, learners, students and non schooling
I have collected a dataset on Employment status. I created the following categories; Pensioners, Formally employed, Informally Employed, Self-employed, and Unemployed. I also have Learners or Students and those not Schooling categories, my question is whether I can have Pensioners, Learners, or Students not schooling under the employment status, or should they all go under the unemployed category? The purpose is to find out whether employment status affects Indigenous knowledge practice of various variables.

I guess that depends on your purpose, which you forgot to tell us! Please edit your post to amend this inflo

I have edited the question.

In economics the definition of "unemployed" is someone who doesn't have a job but is actively looking for one. If these people are not actively looking for a job, they are a third category "not in the labor force". From a statistical perspective, it seems like the most straightforward path would be to keep all of the groups distinct (e.g. pensioners may behave differently then students), unless you have very few observations in each group.

I do, I have two observations in one category of not schooling which means it does not meet the assumptions for the multinomial and the std. error is huge. My worry was placing the two under unemployed because legally they are not supposed to be working but going to school but have dropped out just staying at home. Any advise?

I think there are many possible paths you could take, any of which could be best depending on what you are attempting to achieve. One path would be to create a new category, "not in labor force" which contains all students, pensioners, not schooling, and anyone else who doesn't have a job but isn't looking for one. Another would be to group the "not schooling" with the students and leave the pensioners separate. Another would be to drop the two observations of "not schooling" from your analysis. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve and how much data you have.

Thank you alot.

BUt there may be an issue with your categories, in that they mey not really be mutually exclusive. A Student may have a full-time, or part-time job while going to school/university; a pensioner may also hold a part-time job, some people may hold more than 1 job, etc... So you may have to treat each as their own binomial variables. If some variables have very few observations, yiou may be able to lump them together into "none of the above".

For my study purpose, the idea is to find out whether receiving an income has an influence. I have grouped students with learners because there were few observations for students, also none of them were working including the pensioners, who are elderly and retired who rely on government grants, and also not working, Not schooling has two observations, other categories are ok. I am not sure "none of the above" will make sense as a category under employment status. I don't understand the part of treating each as their own binomial variables.

If you haven't already done that, it may be informative to look at how people in your field usually treat this issue, as your question is not just a statistical one, in my opinion. I think that a good answer to your question should be informed by theory coming from your field of research. It can also be helpful to look at more general standards (e.g. do the national statistical services in the country where you're conducting your research have a classification for employment status? If so, does it have some sort of nested structure you could use?)

Thanks, we have a Statistics agency in the country and I asked this question to a labour statistician who has not responded yet in two days. I will follow up with them, Thank you for the advice.

Perhaps explore the labor force surveys by the International Labour Organization, it is available for many different countries, including questions/categories about employment status: https://webapps.ilo.org/surveyLib/index.php/catalog/LFS/?page=1&ps=15&repo=LFS. In general (always?), there will be three main categories (employed/unemployed/not in labor force) as mentioned by Adam Check, but their scope might vary between different countries.

Thank you very much :-)
